# 'Per X' logging for a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I'm looking to build into an application some custom logging information to use later within other parts other application. In the simplest terms this is a 'per-user' log.

What is the best way to go about this?

```
1. log to dev/production log, then find some way to parse that when I need to information
2. create a custom log file, then parse that when needed
3. log the info to a db text field with the user
```

I've started looking into this and all 3 are viable, I'm curious as to how others have solved this in a standardized manner(perhaps something I haven't thought of).

To reiterate: per-entity logging for a rails application, what is the best method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved through learning log4r(and regular logger) and just working through what I needed. There is no magic.